# Apache2 : DocumentRoot redirect from a www.example.com/destination

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I am setting up an apache2, and I am wondering how I would do this :

I want to redirect  www.example.org/destination to  a certain folder on my server, let's say /home/sites/mydestinationdirectory .

However I do not want to make the actual folder "destination" in /var/Www.

Is this possible in Apache2 and how would I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache's [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.

```
Alias /destination /home/sites/mydestinationdirectory

<Directory /home/sites/mydestinationdirectory>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Another way would be to use `mod_rewrite` for more complex setups.

Comment: The Alias and alias target should always both *have* a slash or both **not** have a slash at the end. Do not mix those!

Comment: And use AliasMatch or Redirectmatch for more complex cases. Most people who use mod_rewrite should really not be using mod_rewrite.